# Easiest way to create a weighted heatmap

Tags: language-agnostic, data-visualization, heatmap

Consider a CSV file with the following data:

```
weight,lat,long
9876,23.44,88.15
1234,27.11,55.33
....
```

What is the easiest way to create a weighted heatmap from this data?

Answers in all languages are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using matplotlib I was able to get this to work:

```
import csv
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    C, Y, X = zip(*r)

    X = [float(x) for x in X]
    Y = [float(y) for y in Y]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.hexbin(X, Y, C, gridsize=200)
    plt.show()
```

However, the `gridsize=200` is just not a good enough resolution, and when using higher values, matplotlib uses ridiculous amounts of memory and is extremely slow, on a data CSV file of ~1000 rows.

It seems to be a known issue that [`hexbin()` has performance issues](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07716.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a derivative of a similar map I built recently...however, at most zoom levels, this one consolidates markers if there is overlap, so you may want to remove that feature. It also uses 5 steps of 'heat' that are doubles of the previous step, so you may also want to make some changes there. And, if you use this literal code, it's looking for some marker icons: `1.png`, `2.png`...`7.png`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Transaction Mapping</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
#wrap {width:960px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;position:relative;}
#map_canvas {width:100%;height:700px;}
#legend_values {position:relative; top:-700px; left:200px;}
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'])){
    $weights=array();
    $lats=array();
    $lngs=array();
    $hdr=(isset($_REQUEST["hdr"]))?$_REQUEST["hdr"]:$hdr=0;
    $file=$_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $data=fopen($file,'r');
    while($row=fgets($data)){
        str_replace("\n","",$row);
        str_replace("\r","",$row);
        if(strlen($row)>0){
            if($hdr<1){
                $cells=explode(",",$row);
                array_push($weights,$cells[0]);
                array_push($lats,$cells[1]);
                array_push($lngs,$cells[2]);
            }
            $hdr--;
        }
    }
    $c=0;?>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="legend_values"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
    echo "var data=[";
    for($i=0;$i<count($weights);$i++){
        if($c>0){echo ",";}
        echo "[".$weights[$i].",".$lats[$i].",".$lngs[$i]."]";
        $c++;
    }
    echo "];\n";
    ?>
    var shopsToShow=Array();
    var openingWindow;
    var map;
    var placesToFilter=Array();
    var MyInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Loading...'});
    var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var a=new Object();
        a.weight=data[i][0];
        a.lat=data[i][1];
        a.lng=data[i][2];
        placesToFilter.push(a);
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
    for(i=0;i<placesToFilter.length;i++){
        if(placesToFilter[i].lng!=0){
            var point2=new google.maps.LatLng(placesToFilter[i].lat,placesToFilter[i].lng);
            bounds2.extend(point2);
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {filterAnnotations();});
    map.fitBounds(bounds2);         

    function filterAnnotations(){

    for (x in shopsToShow) {
        shopsToShow[x].setMap(null);
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(shopsToShow[x], 'click');
    }
    shopsToShow=new Array();

    var found,checkingLocation;
    //20 in the below lines is the height and width of the graphic you're using for the marker
    scaleFactorLongitude = document.getElementById('map_canvas').offsetWidth/20; 
    scaleFactorLatitude = document.getElementById('map_canvas').offsetHeight/20;
    var bounds=map.getBounds();
    var latDelta=(bounds.getNorthEast().lat()-bounds.getSouthWest().lat())/scaleFactorLatitude;
    var longDelta=(bounds.getNorthEast().lng()-bounds.getSouthWest().lng())/scaleFactorLongitude;

    for (m=0; m<placesToFilter.length; m++) {
        checkingLocation=placesToFilter[m];
        checkingLatitude = checkingLocation.lat;
        checkingLongitude = checkingLocation.lng;

        found=false;
        for (x in shopsToShow) {
            if(Math.abs(shopsToShow[x].getPosition().lat()-checkingLatitude) < latDelta &&
               Math.abs(shopsToShow[x].getPosition().lng()-checkingLongitude) <longDelta ){
                shopsToShow[x].weight=(shopsToShow[x].weight*1)+(placesToFilter[m].weight*1);
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ((!found)&&(checkingLongitude!=0)) {
            var point=new google.maps.LatLng(checkingLatitude,checkingLongitude);
            if (bounds.contains(point) == true){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,map: map, icon:'7.png'});
                marker.weight=placesToFilter[m].weight;
                shopsToShow.push(marker);
            }
        }
    }
    //adjust colors and clickability

    var maxweight=shopsToShow[0].weight*1;
    var minweight=shopsToShow[0].weight*1;
    for (i=1;i<shopsToShow.length;i++) {
        if (shopsToShow[i].weight*1>maxweight) {
            maxweight=shopsToShow[i].weight*1;
        }
        if (shopsToShow[i].count*1<minweight) {
            minweight=shopsToShow[i].weight*1;
        }
    }
        var gap=maxweight-minweight;
        var roundToNearest=10;
        if(gap<160){
            roundToNearest=5;
        }
        if(gap<16){
            roundToNearest=1;
        }
        //determine steps
        cat=[];
        var step=Math.ceil((gap/16)/roundToNearest)*roundToNearest;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){
            var n=step*Math.pow(2,i);
            cat.push(n);
        }
        //Math.ceil(number/10)*10;
        if(gap==0){
            cat=[1,2,3,4,5];
        }

        document.getElementById('legend_values').innerHTML="<table id=\"nudge\"><tr><td align=\"center\" width=\"30px\" style=\"padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;background-color:#F0F;\">&le;"+cat[0]+"</td><td align=\"center\" width=\"30px\" style=\"padding:3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:#0F0;\">&le;"+cat[1]+"</td><td align=\"center\" width=\"30px\" style=\"padding:3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:#FF0;\">&le;"+cat[2]+"</td><td align=\"center\" width=\"30px\" style=\"padding:3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:#F60;\">&le;"+cat[3]+"</td><td align=\"center\" width=\"30px\" style=\"padding:3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:#F00;\">&le;"+cat[4]+"</td></tr></table>";
    document.getElementById('legend_values').style.left=((960-document.getElementById('nudge').offsetWidth*1)/2)+'px';

    for (var i = 0; i < shopsToShow.length; i++) {
        var marker = shopsToShow[i];
        var ic;
        //here you're setting the proper icons, so if you were to keep this as is, you'd need to have 7.png, 6.png, etc
        if(marker.weight<cat[4]){ic=7;}
        if(marker.weight<cat[3]){ic=6;}
        if(marker.weight<cat[2]){ic=5;}
        if(marker.weight<cat[1]){ic=4;}
        if(marker.weight<cat[0]){ic=1;}
        marker.setIcon(ic+".png");
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            MyInfoWindow.setContent('Weight:'+this.weight);
            MyInfoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
</script>
<?php   
}
else{?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table><tr><td align="right">File:</td><td><input type="file" name="upfile" id="file" /></td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">First Row is Header:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="hdr" id="hdr" value="1"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr></table>
</form>
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```